# MySQL order by today, past, future

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to use `ORDER BY` with a date to get the records from my table in the following order:

```
TODAY (9 PM)
TODAY (7 PM)
TODAY (9 AM)
TODAY (7 AM)
PAST (3 DAYS AGO)
PAST (2 DAYS AGO)
PAST (1 DAYS AGO)
FUTURE (IN 1 DAY)
FUTURE (IN 2 DAYS)
FUTURE (IN 3 DAYS)
```

Currently I am using:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY 
    IF(DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW()), 0, 1) ASC,
    IF(DATE(my_date) < DATE(NOW()), 0, 1) ASC,
    my_date ASC
```

But that gives me:

```
TODAY (7 AM) - WRONG
TODAY (9 AM) - WRONG
TODAY (7 PM) - WRONG
TODAY (9 PM) - WRONG
PAST (3 DAYS AGO)
PAST (2 DAYS AGO)
PAST (1 DAYS AGO)
FUTURE (IN 1 DAY)
FUTURE (IN 2 DAYS)
FUTURE (IN 3 DAYS)
```

I tried changing the the "today" sorting using `DESC`:

```sql
IF(DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW()), 0, 1) DESC,
```

But then it just sends the records to the very bottom (even below the future results). Is this possible to do with just SQL or will I have to run multiple queries using CodeIgniter's `where()` and merge them using PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will meet the specified requirement:

```sql
SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table t
 ORDER
    BY DATE(t.my_date)=DATE(NOW()) DESC
     , IF(DATE(t.my_date)=DATE(NOW()),t.my_date,DATE(NULL)) DESC
     , t.my_date ASC
```

---

Let's unpack that a little bit.

The first expression in the ORDER BY will evaluate to a `1` (if the conditional test is true), `0` (if it's false), or `NULL` (if one of the expressions is NULL.)  We want descending order, to get the rows for which the condition is 'true' sorted first.

The second expression is an IF function. If the date portion of the my_date value is today's date, then we return `my_date`. We want that sorted in descending order (per the specification.) Otherwise, we want to return a constant, so that all the rest of the rows are going to be considered "equal".

Third, we order by the my_date value in ascending order. This won't affect the rows from today, those are already ordered in descending, so this really only affects the rows that are "equal" up to this point (which would be "not today").  Any rows with my_date value of NULL should wind up last (the first expression in the ORDER BY actually guarantees us that.)

Answer (score 4):

Parado's answer separates the values correctly.  But the ordering also varies by group.  The values are descending for the current day, and then ascending for the other days.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY (case when DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW())
               then my_date
               else date('2000-01-01')
          end
         ) desc,
         my_date asc;
```

The second two groups can be combined.  When the dates are ordered in ascending order, then the past comes before the future.

EDIT:

The purpose of the `date('2000-01-01') is for NULL values (ie. not today) to go last.  You can do this with three part logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY (case when DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW()) then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW())
               then my_date
          end
         ) desc,
         my_date asc;
```

Comment: This is throwing an error, also. what is the purpose of setting the date to 2000-01-01?

Comment: @doitlikejustin . . . The problem was the lack of `end` for the `case`.  The constant is there to be sure that non-current days appear after the current days.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [**CASE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) syntax in `order by` clause and column `my_date` after that as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      WHEN DATE(my_date) = DATE(NOW()) THEN 0
      WHEN DATE(my_date) < DATE(NOW()) THEN 1
      WHEN DATE(my_date) > DATE(NOW()) THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END , DATE(my_date) desc
```

Comment: I believe this will order "today" rows in ascending order rather than in the descending order as specified by OP.

Comment: This is an interesting way to order the dates but as @spencer7593 said, it's not ordering "today" in descending order.

Comment: Hmm still in ascending order, and changing it to `DESC` does not work

Comment: @doitlikejustin what about `DATE(my_date) desc` as above ?

Comment: @Parado that fixed the today sorting but now the rest is out of order... not even sure what order it is in. Looks random when I ran the query just run.